# How to Import Android Ad Libraries

Tags: java, android

I have:

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

As well as several others.  Gradle (Android Studio) refuses to recognize them.  I have read that you import a specific jar, other places I have read that you must import a specific module.  How do I gain access to these libraries?

Comment: You typically need to include the google-play-services Android library project that comes with the Android SDK.

Comment: Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html and choose "Using Android Studio" from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You must Import the Google Play Services library into your Eclipse workspace. Click `File` > `Import`, select `Android` > `Existing Project into Workspace`, and browse to the library project...

if you read the doc the library must be located at:

```
<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/
```

More info:
**[Setting Up Google Play Service](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)**

Comment: You're half right but I did not end up importing as module, but rather as library.  The catch is that you need both the google repository and the play libraries.  Thank you though.